# MPMoviePlayerController - handle phone call

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play a video.
When a call comes, i want to pause and when he completes, i want to continue the video.
I couldn't find relevant solution in my search.
Is this something possible?

Its possible to handle the interruptions using AVAudioSessionDelegate "beginInterruption" and "endInterruption". But when I am setting the session to play back, my movie player sound is not heard at all. 
Does any one know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've to set the session active after endInterruption.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [callEventHandler](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) in Core Telephony framework. I hope, You could find what you want here.

Comment: It will send events only when app is active. This is not the solution.