# How to quit MPMoviePlayerController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to quit the `MPMoviePlayerController` programmatically while playing, instead of pressing done button. Is it possible. Is there any way to simulate Done button click?

Comment: Why it requires? Playing movie completely or stop it somewhere is users concern..

Comment: As per our applications spec... I have to close player, when any incoming call comes...Thats why Any idea?

Comment: You should pause the movie using the delegate methods of UIApplication but you shouldn't quit the controller

Comment: You're presenting the movie player controller from another view? So you can dismiss it?

Comment: @Wain Do you want me to dismiss the parent itself?

Comment: There seems to be an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331921/mpmovieplayercontroller-handle-phone-call

Comment: @Adithya It seems that answer is for normal incoming calls... My application is conference based... I won't get that interruption and all for our local calls.. I guess...

Comment: @Newbee- you can not quit it. this is the final answer..u can stop or pause the player and u can add a uiview then in place of MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: @VivekSehrawat oh ;( I will find another way then... thanx...

Comment: @Newbee -welcome, i have searched a lot their is no legal other way for this..your app will be rejected then

Comment: @VivekSehrawat Is it possible to present a view controller over player.. Its not allowing... There the problem arise...

Comment: @Newbee- no, bt u can present a uiview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31861/discussion-between-vivek-sehrawat-and-newbee)

Comment: @VivekSehrawat I have tried popping the view-controller which is showing the player, even that also not working... :(. Then how do I present a view controller...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have one trick for you. you can take the mpmovieplayer on uiview and then remove the uiview after stoping the player

In ViewController.h

```
      MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
      UIView *view1;
    -(IBAction)cancelPlay:(id)sender;
```

In ViewController.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"try" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
        view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 300)];
        view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [self.view addSubview:view1];
        moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320,300)];
        [view1 addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        [moviePlayerController play];
    }
    -(IBAction)cancelPlay:(id)sender{
        [moviePlayerController stop];
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    }
```